# Why following XPath statement returns all "a" elements?

Tags: perl, xpath

```
print $tree->findvalue('//a[1]');
```

I am using `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` in perl. Now i expect the above statment to return the value of second "a" element but instead it returns the value of all "a" elements in the page. I cant understand Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you have shall return first a-child of every element.
so `//a[1]` will work as follows (result will be 2 nodes):

```
X
 Y
  a <-- give you this
  a
Z
 a <-- and this
 a
```

try `(//a)[1]` instead

Comment: [Xacobeo](http://p3rl.org/Xacobeo) can do this visualisation in an interactive manner.

Answer (score 3):

That XPATH expression looks for all `a` elements at every level of the document and the predicate filter selects the first `a` at every step.

So, depending on how your XML is structured, you might not get *every* `a` element (if there were more than one `a` that were siblings, you would only get the first one of those siblings).

**However, if you intended to just select the first `a` in the document, you could use this expression: `(//a)[1]`**

Wrapping the selection of `//a` in the parenthesis creates a collection that the predicate filter is then applied, selecting the first in the collection, rather than the first `a` encountered at each step of the `//`.